# Plesk 11 / Cents5, how do IP's on multiple ranges work

Tags: networking, centos5

I have a plesk 11 setup running centos5 and i'm a little confused by something.

On the server I have 2 ips from 2 different ranges. They are public IP's pingable from the outside world and working fine.

To not give out the IP's lets say they were 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.2.2.

On a normal linux setup you would define the ifcfg:ethX file as including both the ranges gateways and broadcast address to make it work.

On a plesk environment in /etc/sysscripts/network-scripts/ I see 2 files:

```
File: ifcfg-etho0

DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
BROADCAST="192.168.1.255"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
GATEWAY="129.168.1.1"
HWADDR="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
IPADDR="192.168.1.2"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

and the second file:

```
ifcfg-eth0:1

DEVICE="eth0:1"
IPADDR="192.168.2.2"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
```

my question is how is traffic getting to the 192.168.2.2 address, no where can i find gateways or broadcasts from that range and yet it's working absolutely fine - any ideas?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that IP address and subnet mask is enough to determine broadcast and discovery gateway, check [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Router_Discovery_Protocol)